# How to define a inner class with static value and make it can access outer class object

Tags: java, class

I want to define a class like this:

```
class Tree{
    ArrayList<Node> nodes;
    //...
    class Node{
        static int n = 0;
        private int id;
        public Node(){
            id = n++;
            Tree.this.nodes.add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like that if I define `static int n = 0`, `Node` must be `static`. When I add `static` on `Node`, `Tree.this` doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Don't use an inner class. Pass tree instance to node constructor.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But inner classes were made just for this purpose... How can you justify cluttering code up with an extra reference when inner classes for made *specifically for this reason*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this if it meets your needs:-

```
class Tree{
    ArrayList<Node> nodes;
    private static int n = 0;
    //...
    class Node{
        private int id;
        public Node(){
            id = n++;
            Tree.this.nodes.add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC `n` will need to be default visibility, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Qix Inner class can access outer class' members and vice versa. Also note that this will create a unique id for *every* `Node`, even from different trees. To have each's trees nodes indexed separetely, you can just remove the `static` modifier from `n`.